# How to fix Java problem installing Matlab 2012a (64-bit) in Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit)?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, java, shared-library, matlab

I am trying to install Matlab 2012a (64-bit) in Ubuntu 12.04LTS (64-bit). I have installed Java 7. My Java version is:

```
sabyasachi@sabyasachi-ubuntu:~/Downloads/R2012a_UNIX$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode
```

I am getting the following error while installing Matlab:

```
sabyasachi@sabyasachi-ubuntu:~/Downloads/R2012a_UNIX$ ./install 
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
/tmp/mathworks_18824/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Finished
```

How can I fix this problem?

When I use -v (verbose) option I am getting the following:

```
sabyasachi@sabyasachi-ubuntu:~/Downloads/R2012a_UNIX$ sudo ./install -v
Preparing installation files ...
->  DVD                 = /home/sabyasachi/Downloads/R2012a_UNIX
->  ARCH                = glnxa64
->  DISPLAY             = :0
->  TESTONLY            = 0
->  JRE_LOC             = /tmp/mathworks_26521/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre
->  LD_LIBRARY_PATH     = /tmp/mathworks_26521/bin/glnxa64

Command to run:
/tmp/mathworks_26521/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java  -splash:"/home/sabyasachi/Downloads/R2012a_UNIX/java/splash.png" -Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_26521/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_26521/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_26521/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_26521/java/jarext/axis2/:/tmp/mathworks_26521/java/jarext/guice/:/tmp/mathworks_26521/java/jarext/webservices/ com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/home/sabyasachi/Downloads/R2012a_UNIX" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_26521" 

Installing ...
/tmp/mathworks_26521/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Finished
sabyasachi@sabyasachi-ubuntu:~/Downloads/R2012a_UNIX$
```

Comment: What is the outpuit from: **sudo update-alternatives --config java** ?

Comment: There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).
Selection    Path          Priority   Status ---------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1053      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java              1052      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java          1053      manual mode
Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:

Comment: Hi Sachi, did you finally install Matlab? If so, please consider adding your own answer. If not, please provide additional info or consider deleting this question.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and was able to fix it with following steps. Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command.

1. Install JRE if you don't have it already.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
   ```
2. Invoke the installer with -javadir option

   ```
   sudo ./install -javadir  /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
   ```

Comment: this works for debian too. kudos for the answer, saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

Your Java/JRE probably has nothing to do with this - Matlab is using it's own JRE and that's what's giving you the error (notice the path).

- Make sure Matlab's `java` is executable, with `chmod +x sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java` from the top-level folder (which appears to be `~Downloads/R2012a_UNIX` for you)  [[source](http://kittipatkampa.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/matlab-on-ubuntu-from-install-make-launching-icon-to-uninstall/)]
- Run the installer with:

  ```
  sudo ./install -v
  ```
- This should most probably work; if not, please edit your question with the extended output the verbose (-v) option will give you.

Comment: `sudo` did the trick

Answer (score 1):

As noted, MATLAB has its own (greatly out of date) copy of the JRE, but you can make it use another simply by pointing the MATLAB_JAVA environment variable to the directory containing the JRE you want it to use.

Be aware that Matlab is not compatible with Java 7 (at the moment at least).